# Exporting lines of .lyr file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, layer-file

After I finished make an OD cost matrix layer with function

```
outNALayer = arcpy.na.MakeODCostMatrixLayer(inNetworkDataset, outNALayerName, impedanceAttribute, 15, "", accumulateAttributeName)
```

the result was saved as an .lyr file. But I want to get the lines result which is corresponding to the object circled in the picture.
[image]
(in Arcmap)

Is there any function I can use or are there any other method to save the OD matrix result?

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood the purpose of a layer file. They do ***not*** contain data, just metadata (the path to the actual data, the definition query, the symbology rules,...). Please [Edit] your question to contain the exact procedure you used to save the layer object, and what steps you have tried to access the data. Please use the code formatting block (`{}`) to indent your Python code legibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FRDriveTimeMatrix` is a special Network Analyst group layer that contains a few sublayers such as `Origins`, `Destinations`, and `Lines` + barriers layers. Normally, each layer in the Table of Contents references a dataset on disk only (and stores the definitions of the symbology, the labels, and other visualization properties). However, each of these NA layers is stored in memory within your ArcMap map document. Let's take a look at the Layer Properties window for the `Lines`:

[image]

As long as you work with this map document or another one (in case you done drag-and-drop of the NA group layer between the map documents) that can access the underlying network dataset used for solving the NA problem, you will be able to use the `Lines` features.

However, if you would like to preserve the results of the solved problem, you would need to export the features stored in memory on to disk (into a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class). This can done either using a geoprocessing tool such as `Copy Features` or by right-clicking the `Lines` layer in the Table of Contents and choosing `Data` > `Export Data`. When you have your features saved on disk as a feature class, they won't any longer be connected to their source NA group layer and you can add them to any other map document or process as needed.